# How to do slurs, ties and dynamics in JFugue 5

Tags: java, jfugue

How can I do slurs, ties and dynamics in JFugue 5?

Concerning the dynamics, I would like to have them for one pattern until I place another dynamic and I want to set the dynamic volume (for example "mp" | "setVolume(mp=48)" or something that works like this).

```
Pattern pattern1 = new Pattern();
pattern1.add("C5q. D5i E5q G5q | A5h G5h");
pattern1.add("E5q. F5i E5q D5q | C5w");

Pattern main_voice = new Pattern();
main_voice.add(pattern1);
main_voice.setTempo(120);

Player player = new Player();
player.play(main_voice);
```

I set the music like this, so I don't want to place the dynamics again in every row. Also, it's possible that slurs and ties must go over more than one line. Is this possible?

Comment: *[slur](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slur#Noun)* - *"5. (music) A set of [notes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/note#Noun) that are played [legato](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/legato#Adverb), without separate articulation. 6. (music) The symbol indicating a legato passage, written as an arc over the slurred notes (not to be confused with a tie)."*

Answer (score 0):

Durations in JFugue use the dash character to indicate a note that either keeps playing, continues playing, or stops playing, depending on where it is placed in relation to the duration characters. Notice "q-", "-w-", and "-h" in the line below. This must be applied to notes of the same note value (behind the scenes, the - inhibits the MIDI NoteOff or NoteOn calls).

```
pattern1.add("Ah Gq Cq- | C-w- | C-h Ah");
```

That would play C for a quarter, whole, and half duration with no interruption.

This next line produces the same music, but the measure characters are nice to have to make the music more readable.

```
pattern1.add("Ah Gq Cqwh Ah"); // This produces equivalent music but is harder to read
```

For dynamics that you don't want to add to each line, look into `Pattern.addToEachNoteToken()`. These examples use durations, but you can use dynamics instead (where 'a' is followed by the on-velocity (0-128) and 'd' is followed by the off-velocity (also 0-128)):

```
new Pattern("A B C").addToEachNoteToken("a80") // Results in "Aa80 Ba80 Ca80" 
new Pattern("A B C").addToEachNoteToken("a80 a100") // Results in "Aa80 Ba100 Ca80" (rolls back to a80 for third note) 
new Pattern("A B C").addToEachNoteToken("a80d10 a80d90 a100d90") // Results in "Aa80d10 Ba80d90 Ca100d90"
```

Other than these features, the Staccato string in JFugue was not meant to replicate all of the features of sheet music; it was created to make human-readable music easy to enter and read. So, not all sheet music dynamics are represented in JFugue, although there may be workarounds.